# Unable to fetch data placed in assets folder in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-services

In my sample application I have created a simple json file **institute.json** which has data for **instituteName** and **typ**

I have created a service class called get-data.service.ts to fetch the data from json file placed in assets folder.

But when I am trying to access the URL **`http://localhost:4200/assets/institute.json`** , its redirecting me to the login page of my application.

I have created routeguard in my application for the admin user ,is it because of the routegaurd I am unable to access the URL **`http://localhost:4200/assets/institute.json`**???

Please access my sample app [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/role-based-authentication?file=app%2Fadmin%2Fadmin.component.ts)

When I am trying to fetch data from the service in my admin.component.ts file , its giving me the following error.

**`GET http://localhost:4200/assets/institute.json 404 (Not Found)`**

Any help would be greatly appreciated .Please guide me what am I missing here...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assets folder is not copied to your compiled code.
Its as simple as changing your .angular-cli.json file from

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "styles": ["styles.css"]
  }]
}
```

to

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "styles": ["styles.css"],
    "assets": ["assets"]
  }]
}
```

I fixed it in this sample [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/role-based-authentication-i6ujtu?file=.angular-cli.json).

Comment: but in my application which I am currently working on Eclipse IDE, i don't find any angular-cli.json file.but its present in the stackblitz sample .. where should i make these changes in my sample app running on my Eclipse....!

Comment: You could create the file in the same place as stackblitz. Are you sure you don't have it in your folder somewhere? Be carefull, this file starts with a .(dot) maybe its your operating system that hides this file?

Comment: i have package-lock.json and package.json files in my sample application ,but i dont find angular-cli.json file

Comment: You would definitly need a .angular-cli.json file for this config. Unless you don't use angular-cli?